# how to show in datagridview link as a hyperlink or a button in c# dynamically

Tags: c#, button, datagridview, hyperlink

I have Winform written in C#.

Specifically, I have a DataGridView control that looks like this:

```
No.|Description   | Quantity|   file                  | 
 1 |Beaker        |    2    |c:\PDF\Beaker.pdf        |
 2 |Conical Flask |    21   |c:\PDF\Conical Flask.pdf |
```

What I wanted is when the user clicks on the "File" link opens The PDF file.

then i applied this code thanks goes to mrlucmorin :

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

...

    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        string filename = dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
        if(e.ColumnIndex == 3 && File.Exists(filename))
        {
            Process.Start(filename);
        }

    }
```

works like magic ...

Now What I want is to show the link as a hyperlink or a button dynamically how can i do that

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to use - **DataGridViewLinkColumn**.

Here is the link which describing [DataGridViewLinkColumn](http://en.csharp-online.net/Presenting_Data_with_the_DataGridView_Control_in_.NET_2.0%E2%80%94DataGridViewLinkColumn)

Or If i assume you have already use it then just use property **UseColumnTextForLinkValue** of DataGridViewLinkColumn. Here is the link - [UseColumnTextForLinkValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewlinkcolumn.usecolumntextforlinkvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

You can use like this:

```
DataGridViewLinkColumn fileLink = new DataGridViewLinkColumn();
fileLink.UseColumnTextForLinkValue = true;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, this creates a new column with a button What I want is convert the links in [file] column to a hyperlink or button

Comment: @user3180149 - Okay, I have updated my answer. Please check it out.